# Error trying to import pandas with python

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I installed `pandas` library with Anaconda 1.7.2. When I try import it with python (version 2.7.16), the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

My code in Anaconda is:

```
conda install pandas
```

And my code in Python is:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I have installed `numpy` library and import with python with no problem, for example. So I believe that Anaconda and Python are working well.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It depends on what environment you are running from.There are many causes to this. First of all, *where are you running this code?* Is it in a Jupyter notebook? In your terminal? Are you running a script in a IDE, such as pycharm? Depending on the answer, you have to find out which python distribution you are running, and which virtual environment you are using. For instance, if you have a jupyter notebook, you might be using either a python from `anaconda` or the default `/usr/bin/python` interpreter.`conda install pandas`, will likely make pd available to the former but not to the latter

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed Pandas with Anaconda, you have to run the python shell that is in anaconda environment. Whenever you just type python on the terminal, it will always run the default python. To change this, you need to change the path or use alias.

run

```
which python
```

This will give you the location where your default python is installed.

To change your default python to anaconda's python, refer to this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/886983/how-to-set-anaconda-as-a-default-python

If you do not want to change from default python to anaconda python, just run

```
pip install pandas
```

If you have pip, this will install pandas for the default python. Else install pip first.

Comment: @miriagollmann if this answer has solved your question, you can accept if by clicking the checkmark on the side. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

!pip install

Or use [Conda install SITE](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas)

And paste code...